# Override coverpages page numbering behaviour of exam class

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, exam

According to the [`exam` class documentation §11.6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf#page=108), the behaviour of the `coverpages` environment is defined as such:

> Note that if your document has a `coverpages` environment (see section 12), then those
>   pages will *not* be counted in `\numpages`; ...

Now, I want to specifically override this particular behaviour: in other words, the page(s) containing `\begin{coverpages} ... \end{coverpages}` to be page 1 (and so on), and all other pages following it to be page (last cover page number + 1) and so on.

Furthermore, I would like all page numbering to have the format: `Page x of y`, where x and y are Hindu-Arabic numerals. This is trivial for the actual question pages, but I also wished to redefine the numbering of the `coverpages` environment to be `arabic` instead of `roman`, which is apparently hard-coded into the `exam` class.

A small M(N)WE [minimum (not) working example]:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}

% \addtocounter{... content page + number of cover pages? }
\coverfooter{}{Page \thepage{} of \totalnumpages{}}{}
\footer{}{Page \thepage{} of \totalnumpages{}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{coverpages}
    Here is my cover page. 
\end{coverpages}

\begin{questions}
    \question[]{
        ...
    }
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

On a partially related note, I found that both the `titlepage` environment as well as `maketitle` exhibit similar behaviour by resetting the page counter, so I have two 'page 1's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/gslv9p/override_coverpages_page_numbering_behaviour_of/fs6umpd/), courtesy of [/u/JimH10](https://www.reddit.com/user/JimH10):

> You are going to want to find the cls file. I get this.

```
$ kpsewhich exam.cls
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/exam/exam.cls
```

> Open it in your editor and save it, perhaps under the name myexam.cls, in the directory containing the document file.
>
> Now have some fun. I had a quick look and it seems to be a very well-written class file. For example, under *\newenvironment{coverpages}* in line 1022 it says this.

```latex
\pagenumbering{roman}%
```

> I think you want to try changing that to *arabic*.